# como traer registros de tablas relacionadas con ajax en .net mvc?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo una relacion de muchos a muchos y quiero traer los registros a una vista, estoy utilizando el metodo $.ajax() de jquery pero despues de ejecutarse el codigo en el navegador dice que hay una referencia circular.
Que andara mal?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La referencia circular es debido a la forma de como tienes tu estrucutra de BD o al query que estás solicitando a la BD.

Comment: es por que en tu usuario tienes un listado de actividades y cuando se intenta serializar la actividad tienes una referencia a usuario  y entonces intenta serializar el usuario  pero cuando va al usuario hay un listado de actividades y así se produce el bucle y manda el error, una forma fácil de evitarlo es seleccionando solo las propiedades que necesitas de ambas entidades y crear un objeto que contenga esas propiedades

Comment: osea un viewModel?

Comment: si quieres un modelo de vista o lo dejas como objeto anónimo cualquiera de las 2 te funcionara